# Code for automating incremented ZIP compression?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to ZIP a folder of 800 pictures, with each ZIP file containing only 10 or less pictures, so I should end up with 80 ZIP files. If anyone knows the BAT file code to do this, I would be very appreciative.  I also do NOT want to delete the files after they've been zipped.

I know that I'll probably be using 7-Zip, but I just can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: 7zip and probably most compressing tools, can only divide by size not amount of files https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/volume.htm and you will need every single zip to extract single file. You should specify the purpose or expecting result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `PowerShell`:

```
# Setup variables (Change)
$ZipFolder = "T:\YourFolder\WithFiles\ToZip"
$7Zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$NewZipsFolder = "T:\FolderToPut\AllOfThe\ZipsIn"

# Script Variables
$pendingFiles = @() 
$fileNumber = 1

# Get a list of all the files to be zipped
Get-ChildItem $ZipFolder | sort $_.FullName | ForEach-Object { $pendingFiles += $_.FullName  }

# While there are files still to zip 
While($pendingFiles){

    # Select first 10 files to zip and zip them
    $ToZip = $pendingFiles | Select -First 10 
    & $7Zip "a" "$NewZipsFolder\File-$fileNumber.7z" $ToZip 

    # Remove first 10 zipped files from pending files array
    $pendingFiles = $pendingFiles | Where-Object { $ToZip -notcontains $_ } 
    $fileNumber++ 
}
```

This will create a list of all the file that need to be zipped. Then zip them up in batches of 10 files using `7z.exe` (7-zip).

**Note**: For the variables `$ZipFolder` & `$NewZipsFolder` do not put a trailing backslash on the folder paths (`\`).

Comment: This worked!  Thanks SO MUCH!  You just saved me hours of work!  I did change the .7z to .zip for what I needed, but it did what it was supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

You could store an list of files in Powershell using something along the lines of

```
$fileList = Get-Item -Path "C:\MyPhotosDir\*"
```

Then set an alias for 7zip

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
```

Then create a loop with a counter along the lines of

```
$i = 1
foreach $file in $fileList 
    #Build foder name name
    $folderDir = "C:\MyPhotoArchive$($i - ($i % 10) + 1).7z"
    sz a -t7z $folderDir $file.filename
end for
```

I have been writing in VB for a short while and so apologies if the Powershell syntax is a bit off. Essentially that should add 10 files to "C:\MyPhotoArchive1", 10 files to "C:\MyPhotoArchive2". I haven't added files to an archive using 7zip for a long time but I think the call just uses a `a` and should add files to an archive, creating one when needed.